# Going on holiday from an airport with mild temperature, can airport security detect this and think it is Coronavirus?

Tags: airports, airport-security, covid-19

I am going on holiday very soon and I have a mild temperature, I feel quite well and in my honest opinion, I am fit to travel. I will take my medication with me etc. I also look quite well.

I have a worry though. Can airport metal detectors/x-rays in the UK or in any airport detect temperature? If so and they want to pull me over for a check I will allow more time for airport security.

Also, do you think they might have to test/quarantine me for coronavirus as the symptoms [according to the NHS](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/) are:

> - a cough
> - a high temperature
> - shortness of breath

I have a medium temperature and a mild cough (2 of 3 symptoms). It would be a pain and really upsetting to ruin my holiday.

Comment: Locked as the health and virus situation has changed massively since it was asked and OP would no longer travel under the same health circumstances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither the metal detectors, nor the full body scanners currently in use at UK airports are designed to measure or detect body temperature. However [infrared camera systems](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jeremybogaisky/2020/02/10/we-are-running-as-fast-as-we-can-coronavirus-sparks-surge-in-demand-for-infrared-fever-detection-equipment/#5f20c5ed60c9) designed to do so are fairly simple to install, and are [known to be installed](https://abcnews.go.com/Technology/story?id=7486026&page=1) at various airports worldwide to catch fever sufferers. On a far simpler level the same kind of non-contact technology is [also being used](https://www.keeptalkinggreece.com/2020/02/04/athens-international-airport-coronavirus-measures/)  in handheld thermometers.

At the moment this is primarily targeted at travellers from the highest-risk areas (i.e. mainland China). Since known cases in the UK are still extremely rare, it's likely you would be recognised as having a high probability of having some other virus (they are rather common after all). Having said that, the situation is subject to change, so keep following the news, and consider the worries of your fellow passengers (e.g. carry tissues & hand sanitizer)

Comment: Many destination airports do temperature screening now via IR camera or handheld thermometers. If found high, there is chance that you will be quarantined.

Comment: That said, the UK has has a super spreader, so I won't be surprised if British authorities are already on high alert.